# R hist default xlim?

Tags: r

I am writing an R function that calls `hist`.  `hist` takes an optional argument `xlim` that defaults to (per the documentation) `range(breaks)`.  However, as you might expect, when I call `hist(..., xlim=range(breaks),...)`, R complains that `breaks` isn't found.

The issue here is that I would like for my function `calls_hist` to ALSO accept an optional argument `xlim`.  However, it seems that whatever my default argument for `xlim` is, I can't simply pass it down to `hist`.

I *could* do some logic workarounds here to ultimately accomplish my goal, but I'm pretty sure that there's a better way.  What is the "real" default argument to `xlim`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively complex.

When you call `hist`, which is an S3 generic, it dispatches the method `hist.default`. If you did not specify breaks, then `breaks` defaults to `"Sturges"`. This argument is matched inside the body of `hist.default`, and the function `nclass.Sturges` is called on your `x` variable to generate an appropriate integer number of breaks. This number is then passed on the function `pretty` to determine the actual breaks. The `range` of this vector is taken as the default `xlim`.

So the "real" default method of calculating `xlim` given a vector `x` is:

```r
predict_xlim <- function(x) range(pretty(range(x), n = nclass.Sturges(x)))
```

We can try this on some random samples to see if it works:

```r
set.seed(1)

vec1 <- rnorm(1000)
vec2 <- rexp(1000)
vec3 <- runif(1000)
```

If we have the xlims correct, then the following code should put vertical red lines at the extreme edges of the outer histogram breaks (and hence the limits of the x axis):

```
hist(vec1)
lims <- predict_xlim(vec1)
lims
#> [1] -3.5  4.0
abline(v = lims, col = 'red')
```

[image]

```r
hist(vec2)
lims <- predict_xlim(vec2)
lims
#> [1] 0.0 7.5
abline(v = lims, col = 'red')
```

[image]

```r
hist(vec3)
lims <- predict_xlim(vec3)
lims
#> [1] 0 1
abline(v = lims, col = 'red')
```

[image]

So, to answer your question, you can define your function like this:

```r
draw_a_histogram <- 
  function(x, xlim = range(pretty(range(x), n = nclass.Sturges(x))), ...) {
    hist(x, xlim = xlim, ...)
  }
```

This allows you to call your function without `xlim`

```
draw_a_histogram(rnorm(500))
```

[image]

*Or* with a specified xlim

```r
draw_a_histogram(rnorm(500), xlim = c(-1, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>